# Sqlite c/c++ api who is respnsible for freeing pointer from sqlite3_column_text

Tags: c++, sqlite

The function `sqlite3_column_text` returns const char* 
Should I free the returned pointer or sqlite will free it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sqllite` will free it. check [**here**](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob) the quote from `sqllite` api reference:

The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until `sqlite3_step()` or `sqlite3_reset()` or `sqlite3_finalize()` is called. The memory space used to hold strings and BLOBs is freed automatically. ***Do not pass the pointers returned `sqlite3_column_blob()`, `sqlite3_column_text()`, etc. into `sqlite3_free()`.***